# Case insensitive search in tmux's copy mode?

Tags: tmux

So in tmux's copy mode you can search text with the `?` (at least if it's in vi mode). However, it only finds matches with the same case. I also want matches that have a different case. So, when I search for `cow` it should also find matches like `Cow`, `COW` and even `CoW`. It doesn't seem to do this by default.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make the search case insensitive? I couldn't find it in the documentation or by searching on the internet.

ATM I use GNU Screen and I use the copy mode all the time. Trying to switch to tmux now but if this feature isn't in I really can't switch.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this?

Comment: @jmsu Well, I noticed that when I installed it on my MacBook recently, it magically worked. Maybe the package on my Debian system is too old. I'm planning to check it out soon.

Comment: @jmsu I don't have this problem on a Ubuntu system where I installed tmux from source. I'm using version 1.9a.

Comment: I am using byobu installed with apt on crunchbang linux and the tmux version is 1.6. Good to know it works on newer versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the version I used when I posted the question was (or is by now) a bit outdated. I don't have this problem in tmux 1.9a. In this version, the behavior seems to be smartcase. I still didn't find an option for it though, but this is the behavior I want anyway, so it's good.